# aspnet_membership password decryption via PHP

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc, cryptography, aes

I've spent better half of the day trying to figure out the problem I have, and I'm at a dead end it seems.

I have a ASP application(no access to actual code, just database), in which the user passwords are stored in aspnet_membership > Password column, it also has a salt.

I've also got a copy of the machine key file, which from what I understand contains the keys neede to decryot the password?

```
 <machineKey validationKey="**validation key**" decryptionKey="**decryption key**" validation="SHA1" decryption="AES"/>
```

i've tried a bunch of different ways of doing this, with open ssl, with different libraries, etc. However I seem to lack knowledge when it comes to this. I'm currently trying to use https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib library to decrypt the password:

```
$cipher = new AES(); // could use AES::MODE_CBC
        // keys are null-padded to the closest valid size
        // longer than the longest key and it's truncated
        //$cipher->setKeyLength(128);
        $cipher->setKey(**decrypt key**);
        // the IV defaults to all-NULLs if not explicitly defined
        $cipher->setIV($salt);

        echo $cipher->decrypt($password);
```

However any way i'm trying todo this, I get either random return or false. I've got a very limited amount of info about the version of AES running on the ASP application or any other encryption info. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. Just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security.  Iterate over an HMAC with a random salt for about a 100ms duration and save the salt with the hash. Use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: The salt ensures that identical passwords hash to different values so knowing one password will not review other passwords. On initial save of the derivation a unique (random) salt is created and must be saves with the derivation, on verification the salt is set to the saved value.

Answer (score -1):

Hi This MachineKey has nothing to do with Salt, the salt is generating by the code at run-time using the Password provided.

.NET framework using Rfc2898DeriveBytes for encryption
Something like this

```
using (Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveByte = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, 16, 1000))
        {
            salt = rfc2898DeriveByte.Salt;
            bytes = rfc2898DeriveByte.GetBytes(32);
        }
```

Comment: So what the salt is used for then?

Comment: @IkramShah the salt is not "generated at run-time using the Password provided", it is not related to the password and generally is a random value. While Rfc2898 (otherwise known as PBKF2) is a secure password verification method the OP is using encryption which is not a secure method.

Comment: @SauliusAntanavicius The salt ensures that identical passwords hash to different values so knowing one password will not review other passwords.